# Use as in select statement on select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a request with a select statement that works in Oracle, but when I execute it in SQL Server it throws an exception; the request is :

```
SELECT non_existant FROM 
(SELECT rownum AS non_existant ,cab, validite FROM tmp_rapprochement) 
WHERE validite like '%non_existant%'
```

The error is :

```
Msg 207, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 2 Nom de colonne non valide : 'rownum'.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is `rownum` a column in the table, or Oracle's `rownum` functionality?  If the latter, take a look at SQL Server's `row_number()` functionality:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3878bca7-6418-40e7-b77f-1ebe5a66ae24/how-can-the-rownum-of-oracle-be-represented-in-tsql

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `rownum` is not a valid column name (I'm glad Google translate is there to help)

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid column name 'rownum'.

You need to fix that error first - make sure that all columns from the `select`'s list are defined in the table.

Once you get that out of your way, you would need to provide an alias for the inner select, like this:

```
SELECT non_existant FROM
    (SELECT rownum AS non_existant ,cab, validite FROM tmp_rapprochement) x
    -- x above is an alias, it is mandatory in SQL Server syntax.
WHERE validite like '%non_existant%'
```

**EDIT** It appears that you are porting this query from Oracle, so `rownum` is not a real column. In this case you should replace it with a `row_number` function, like this:

```
SELECT non_existant FROM
    (SELECT row_number() OVER (Order by cab) AS non_existant
    ,  cab --                           ^^^ Put rapprochement's primary key there
    ,  validite FROM tmp_rapprochement
) x -- x is an alias, it is mandatory in SQL Server syntax.
WHERE validite like '%non_existant%'
```

Comment: That, and `rownum` isn't a valid SQL Server function

Comment: the probleme is not in alias, but in "rownum as non_existant" !

Comment: @ucef Alias is another problem that the OP will necessarily hit pretty quickly, once he fixes the naming error.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - two things. **1**:  ucef *is* the OP.   **2** I believe the OP is using Oracle's [`rownum`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) function, which is not a column in the table, but an actual function that is being aliased.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I was wondering if it were Oracle-related, but the tag says `sql-server-2008-r2`... I didn't notice ucef is the OP, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: yes that's right , but "rownum as non_existant" is also a problem , and i think that i will use row_number instead of rownum !!

Comment: @ucef By chance, are you porting this query from another RDBMS?

Comment: i have only oracle and sql server 2008 , i try this and it work for the moment " row_number() OVER (Order by cab) AS non_existant"  , but i have another problem, cab is varchar, can i do an order with varchar type !!

Comment: @ucef If you have an index on `cab` it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight there isn't any index on cab.

Comment: You should use whatever is the table's primary key in the `OVER` clause.

Comment: There is no primary key for this table Mr dasblinkenlight, it's probleme to do order by with varchar type ?!!